# How do I fetch distinct joined records in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

I'm using Rails 3.0.10. A `Building` has_many `Floors`, and a `Floor` has_many `Suites`. I would like to fetch all the `Buildings` with at least one `Suite`. (Not every building has suites in it; some are still under construction, for example.)

Some caveats:

- I only want the unique records, so something like `Building.joins(:floors, :suites)` doesn't work.
- There are a lot of Buildings. I don't want to bring back a huge collection locally and then `#uniq` it.
- I'd prefer to avoid string references where possible. For example, I don't want to do something like `Building.joins(:floors, :suites).select("distinct buildings.id")`.
- This can be done in a single SQL query -- something like `select distinct buildings.id from buildings inner join floors on floors.building_id = buildings.id inner join suites on suites.floor_id;`. So it's best if this approach also takes only one query.

What's the best way to go about this using ActiveRecord / ARel / anything else semantic that uses Rails core? I've come up with several different ways of doing this but I'm not sure what's the most canonical.

Answer (score 1):

With 3 Sql-Queries:

```
Building.where(:id => Floor.where(:id => Suite.all.collect(&:floor_id).uniq).collect(&:building_id))
```

Comment: IMO, this is not a good approach because you load every `Suite` in every `Floor` into memory. That's a lot of unnecessarily instantiated objects! We only want to fetch the Buildings here.

Comment: Add counter_caches to your floors and you only need 2 sql queries..?

Comment: That wouldn't stick with Rails core, which breaks one of the conditions I mentioned above. Also, if SQL can do it in a relatively simple statement, it feels like Rails should be able to as well.